# Changing Language Settings Resets App or Creates Another Instance of the App

Tags: android, locale

I am having issues with supporting multiple languages. I need help with understanding what is happening. What I am noticing is that whenever I change languages e.g. change language from English to French, and return back to my app the app will restart. This causes a number of issues, of course, because this behavior is not expected. Particularly there are issues when Fragments are visible because the lifecycle of the Fragment resets (onCreateView is called again) but the requests do not call as they are competing with requests on the Activity level behind it.

I have tried to prevent this from happening by using onConfigurationChanged, however, I am not sure of what to add to it other than the super. In another post it was suggested to refresh my views before the super. But ultimately I just want my app to not reset lifecycle when changing language.

```
   @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

I also added local to my manifest under my Activity nodes

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
```

What is the proper way to not have any changes in the app made when changing languages. The responses to this question have been unclear. Anyone have clear instructions that actually work?

Answer (score 0):

Changing languages is a really rare event.  Even most multilingual people never do it, as keyboards allow you to change input languages independently.  You're probably better off just living with it, or properly implementing onSaveInstanceState/onRestoreInstanceState to properly save all your state.